# Laravel Mix and alpine 3.14 permission error

Tags: php, docker, npm

I am trying to upgrade my docker image from php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13 to php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.14, in which this issue happened.

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/app/public/mix-manifest.json'`

Dev team is currently use Laravel Mix to generate static files.

Logs:

```
/var/www/app # npm run development

> development
> mix

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

● Mix █████████████████████████ sealing (92%) asset processing SourceMapDevToolPlugin
 attached SourceMap

internal/fs/utils.js:332
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/app/public/mix-manifest.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1528:35)
    at File.write (/var/www/app/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/File.js:211:12)
    at Manifest.refresh (/var/www/app/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Manifest.js:75:50)
    at /var/www/app/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/webpackPlugins/ManifestPlugin.js:21:48
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/var/www/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.emitAssets (/var/www/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:850:19)
    at /var/www/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:438:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/var/www/app/public/mix-manifest.json'
}
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.14

ARG COMPONENT
ARG APP_ENV
ARG SRC_DIR

# Update & add nginx
RUN apk update && \
    apk add nginx && mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx/ && \
    chmod 777 -R /var/lib/nginx/tmp
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Give permission to nginx folder
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
RUN chmod 755 /var/lib/nginx/tmp/

# Add php.ini
COPY ./docker/${COMPONENT}/php.ini /etc/php7/php.ini

# Add entrypoint
COPY ./docker/${COMPONENT}/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Install nodejs, npm
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm

# Create source code directory within container
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app

# Add source code from local to container
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY ${SRC_DIR} .

# Grant permission for folders & install packages
RUN chmod 777 -R bootstrap storage && \
    cp ./env/.env.${APP_ENV} .env && \
    composer install

RUN rm -rf .env
RUN npm install && npm run ${APP_ENV} && rm -rf node_modules

# Expose webserver ports
EXPOSE 80 443

# Command-line to run supervisord
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

What I have tried:

- `rm -rf ./node_modules` and install again
- `npm config set unsafe-perm true` before running npm
- `RUN npm config set user 0 && npm config set unsafe-perm true` before npm install

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I met the same problem today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost a year later, I am facing my nemesis once again, and this time I told myself that I would resolve this issue once and for all.
And for whom facing this issue in the future, this is what you need to run Laravel-Mix with Nodejs on an Alpine Image

There are 2 options:

#1
If you are stubborn, run it with an unofficial image of nodejs 14 built from musl instead of official provided package from Alpine Repository.
Then extract and add executables (node14.4.0 and npm6.14.5) to PATH

```
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine3.15
ARG SRC_DIR
...
# setting up packages bla bla
...

# Install nodejs 14 from unofficial repo instead of
# This will not work RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
RUN wget https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.4.0/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64-musl.tar.xz -P /opt/
RUN tar -xf /opt/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64-musl.tar.xz -C /opt/
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64-musl/bin"
...

WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY ${SRC_DIR} .
...
RUN npm install 
# Generating static
RUN npm run dev
...
```

#2
Using multistage build to build static with a fixed version of node instead of installing node on php alpine image (this was hint by my supervisor, which I did not understand why I was never thinking of before, silly me)

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS node_builder
ARG SRC_DIR

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/mix
WORKDIR /var/www/mix

COPY ${SRC_DIR} ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install 
# Generating static into /var/www/mix
RUN npm run dev

FROM php:8-fpm-alpine3.15 as php_final
...
# setting up packages bla bla
...
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY ${SRC_DIR} .

COPY --from=node_builder /var/www/mix/public ./public/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To who may also meet this issue, I re-installed nodejs in my CentOS 7 environment and solved the issue. The nodejs version is also same as the previous one (v14.18.1).

Comment: Oh, I see, so that might be nodejs version compatibility with the alpine 3.14. Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it and update the result

Comment: I think it's permission issue related to nodejs. I reinstalled and used the same version of nodejs and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

my folder owner was root
change of ownership helped

chown admin:admin public -R

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).